# Correct name for Water Butt / Rain Barrell Tap/Valve/Shutoff Fitting?

Tags: irrigation, rain-barrel

Its difficult to find a *suitable* tap/valve/shutoff for water butts.

This is also made worse by most tap/valves not having a backing flange which allows proper sealing up against the water butt.

What is the correct name for this fitting with the flange?

The threads are usually labelled 1/2" BSP, 3/4" BSP, 1" BSP

The following picture contains a fitting without a flange, its not suitable as you have no backing to create a seal.

[image: wrong fitting]

These following pictures contain the **correct** fitting, but what is the **name** of this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably "flanged shutoff valve" but I can't easily verify that that gets suitable results in your local area. Given BSP threads, it's not the same as mine. "Bulkhead shutoff valve" might be an alternative, as the  flanged screw gasket-sealed connection (without always being associated with a valve) is a "bulkhead fitting."

Answer (score 0):

A fitting with a flange that can seat against a wall is a 'bulkhead fitting'.   This is the first result I got when I searched for 'bulkhead fitting valve'.

[image: PVC quarter turn valve with bulkhead fitting]

As an aside, I very much recommend springing for a brass bulkhead fitting.